# Thumbnail is not added when sent to stdout but works when made a file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to convert a Mp4 to a Mp3 using [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1184418/535078) with the following ffmpeg comand

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i cover.jpg -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 256k -c:v copy -map 0:a:0 -map 1:v:0 output.mp3
```

But when I try to run the command via terminal to stdout

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i cover.jpg -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 256k -c:v copy -map 0:a:0 -map 1:v:0 -f mp3 - > output.mp3
```

So I can avoid making files in between the next process, the resulting file does not have the thumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pictures require ID3v2 tags which FFmpeg writes at the start of the file, and after the audio payload has been muxed in. Since it can't seek in the pipe, ffmpeg can't do what you're asking for.

Comment: but ffmpeg _can_ [add in ID3v2 tags](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#AVOptions) and even when I run the command with those it does not work when using pipe, I feel there must be a way with ffmpeg

Comment: FFmpeg does not write 'attached pictures' at the beginning of the process, but waits. With a piped output, it can no longer seek to the beginning.

Comment: I suppose you mean "Iffmpeg _can't_ do what you're asking for"?

Comment: Yes, corrected.